# Remote string replacement using GIT/Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am changing an URL in hundreds of config files across multiple projects and repositories for all HEADs in all branches.

Using a [script](http://%20https://github.com/omerkarabacak/bulk-find-and-replace-in-git-repositories/blob/master/findandreplace.py) to checkout, sed files, commit, and then push all branches would work, but since I have a large number of branches, this approach can take a huge time.

I'm looking for an API for bulk replace (sed?) and commit operations from bitbucket server without the need to checkout every branch locally.

Does bitbucket has any tools or API to execute this task? (remote bulk operations)

Comment: Can't you automatically create pull requests from a `diff` or patch file and merge those?

Comment: I need to do it hundreds of branches in repos. I'd like to do it, but without checking branches out.

Comment: You don't have to create branches to create a PR as far as I know. But that might depend on your setup. You'd only need one branch for the actual changes, which actually is what branches are for. But the question is whether individually changing all those config files is a great idea of you have such issues doing just that. Why not keep those configuration values centralized to pull them when required or at checkout or install time?

Comment: Yes. No need to create branches. But I have to change lots of branches. The whole point is avoiding checking out files to replace them.